# Can Windows 7 ultimate and ubuntu 10.10 work together as a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid problems when installing Ubuntu and Windows 7 in dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18560/how-to-avoid-problems-when-installing-ubuntu-and-windows-7-in-dual-boot)

Can Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu 10.10 work as a dual boot system? If so then how?
If we can do it please give me the answer as fast as you can.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have both Windows (any version, actually) and Ubuntu working in parallel.
The Windows Installer wouldn't like any other operating system installed and might suggest removing it.
The Ubuntu installer is happy to leave a working operating system and sit besides it.
So what I suggest is installing Windows first (which you most probably already have) and install Ubuntu afterwards. The installer will ask you where to install and what to do with existing operating systems.
Upon successful installation you will be presented with a boot loader (GRUB) that allows you to select the operating system that is to be started.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can and am pretty sure this was answered somewhere else about Windows 7 and Ubuntu but anyway you only need to do the following to have them Dual boot together:

1. Install Windows 7 **FIRST** Do NOT!! install Ubuntu first then Windows or you will have to do some additional steps. Install Windows 7 first.
2. After you have it install (Do not worry about partition space and the likes) then insert the Live CD from Ubuntu 10.10 and boot from it. I do not recommend loading the Wubi to avoid some problems that sometime happen with it. Instead BOOT from the Ubuntu Live CD (you need to either change your Bios Setup to boot from CD but most PCs/Laptops that have a CDROM/DVDROM already boot by default from the CD/DVD. After you have booted from the Live CD continue with the installation of Ubuntu and it will be a breeze since you can select how much space you want for Windows and for Ubuntu in one easy draggable way.
3. After Ubuntu finished the Boot manager for Windows 7 and Ubuntu will be GRUB. It will be just an easy way to select which operating system to boot from.

Answer (score 2):

I have a dual installation. To keep things clean I keep my operating systems in separate partions.

NTFS for windows installation
EXT4 for ubuntu
SWAP for ubuntu also swap space

The procedure is quite straight forward. Intalling both operating systems Windows preferably first. And you use grub loader to pick one in the beggining.

If for some reason you cannot see your windows option in the grub loader I can guide you to add the entry to it and make it work.

Recently I was glad to figure out how I can also boot my windows installation from a VirtualBox inside ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggests, Install windows 7 first, and then resize the partition from within windows (I suggest this from experience). To do this, right click on my computer, click manage, and go to devices. Then resize the hard drive to leave the amount of free space you want ubuntu to have. Do not format the empty space.

Restart the system with the ubuntu live CD/USB, and follow the install instructions. When you get to the part about disk space, choose to use the available free space.

As said before, ubuntu will provide a boot loader that allows you to choose your OS on startup.