# What to install on ssd partition

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good partition method to combine an SSD boot drive with a 1TB data drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62152/whats-a-good-partition-method-to-combine-an-ssd-boot-drive-with-a-1tb-data-driv)

Plan to duel boot windows 7 and Ubuntu from a 120gb ssd. What's a good amout of space to allocate? I have 8 gigs of ram and would like to hibernate, but I could go without it..  I have plenty of space on a regular boring hard drive for the parts that don't need ssd speed

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This question has many duplicates and will likely be closed. To point you in the direction of a good answer, I did a search here for the [partitioning](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning?sort=votes&pagesize=50) tag, sorted by votes. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62152/whats-a-good-partition-method-to-combine-an-ssd-boot-drive-with-a-1tb-data-driv) is a good example of what you need to know, [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18560/how-to-avoid-problems-when-installing-ubuntu-and-windows-7-in-dual-boot) is another. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well , minimum requirement is 15GB , and since you said you have lot of available space, you can go with 30-40 GB(20 GB for root and remaining for /home partition). Create multiple partitions so that you can give it to either windows/Linux depending on your requirement.

Comment: So root should go on the ssd and home on the regular hard drive? Or both on the ssd?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference . So u can do either of these